# Selenium starts new socket listener on startup

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting some strange errors when using Selenium to make automated tests for my C# product. I'm using firefox to run the tests but, as you can see below, the product is running on chrome (I haven't had any issues with this in the past). I am pretty sure they are because of the following observation I have made.

When I open selenium.bat to begin my automated test it starts a SocketListener on port 4444, as expected. Throughout the test, however, it continues to open SocketListeners on various ports (not 4444 of course).

this is how I instantiate selenium

```
this.Selenium = new Selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", this.url, this.storageLocation);
```

these are some (but not all) of the points where I observe that Selenium is starting new SocketListeners

```
this.Selenium.Start();
//* ....... *//
this.OpenPageWithRetry(Waits.TestStart, Waits.TestAdditional);
this.Selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(Waits.Default);
```

and any other time selenium fails for some reason (i.e. it didn't find the element it was looking for).

the problem this creates is that when selenium fails no errors are caught and it stalls out indefinitely on a wait condition (or something like that), which means it never ends. I've run the same test on a friend's computer (we work on the product together) and it ran just fine for him so I imagine its not the code but something else running in the background. Here is my batch file that I execute to run the code, and also which opens the command prompt window where I view the commands going through selenium (like when new SocketListeners are created)

```
prompt $
cls

NET STOP "SeleniumRC"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\Users\ethorne\Documents\stratus\Stratus.Selenium\selenium-server.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates

pause
```

edit: I am not starting multiple threads at any point, so I shouldn't see multiple socketListeners being started throughout the test.

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Each WebDriver: Chrome, Selenium, and Firefox all start on a random local higher port number to listen for [JSON Wire Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) .   When WebDriver code sends commands to webdriver instances, they send those commands through that local port.   Even when Grid starts webdriver instances, I believe the same thing happens in the background.  So, it is normal to see that port start for each and every WebDriver thread you start.

Comment: That's what I said. If you run one thread locally, then WebDriver will start a single JSON Wire listener on a random higher port, regardless of what browser you use.

Comment: if the WebDriver starts a JSON Wire listener for each thread (which is just the one, local), what reasons could I be seeing multiple starting? They come in bursts too, the console window shows 3 or 5 in a row starting at certain points (my aforementioned friend runs the same tests on his machine and sees no additional listeners starting). Sorry if I'm not understanding you correctly, but I still have yet to be able to solve this problem after several days of work

Comment: Why are you using "new Selenium"?  That is the old Selenium 1.0 version.  Who uses that anymore?  Do you have a good reason why you need to use the old Selenium?   That would explain the wierd behavior you are seeing.